# getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) showing error

Tags: android

getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) shows error in the following code. Can you please help me with this code. I am kind of stuck in this and cannot proceed ahead without it so please help me with this one.

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RatingBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import navdrawerexample1.models.MovieModel;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<MovieModel> movieModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MovieAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MovieModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        movieModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView=inflater.inflate(resource,null);
        }
        ImageView ivMovieIcon;
        TextView tvMovie;
        TextView tvTagline;
        TextView tvYear;
        TextView tvDuration;
        TextView tvDirector;
        RatingBar rbMovieRating;
        TextView tvCast;
        TextView tvStory;

        ivMovieIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        tvMovie = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMovie);
        tvTagline = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTagline);
        tvYear = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvYear);
        tvDuration = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
        tvDirector = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDirector);
        rbMovieRating = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbMovie);
        tvCast = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCast);
        tvStory = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStory);

        tvMovie.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getMovie());
        tvTagline.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getTagline());
        tvYear.setText("Year: " + movieModelList.get(position).getYear());
        tvDuration.setText("Duration:" + movieModelList.get(position).getDuration());
        tvDirector.setText("Director:" + movieModelList.get(position).getDirector());

        //rating bar

        rbMovieRating.setRating(movieModelList.get(position).getRating()/2);

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (MovieModel.cast cast : movieModelList.get(position).getCastList()){
            stringBuffer.append(cast.getName() + ", ");
        }
        tvCast.setText(stringBuffer);
        tvStory.setText("Cast:" + movieModelList.get(position).getStory());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: cannot resolve method getsystemservice

Comment: The method belongs to context class , so change to `context.getSystemService();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

to this:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

Replace

```
 inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

with

```
   inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: @SantoshShrestha Always Welcome Bro

Answer (score 0):

change,

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

with

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

**Note:** You need to pass context inside your constructor.

Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

The method getSystemService belongs to the class Context, so you have to run it on a context but you're running it from non Android class.

So access getSystemService using the context passed from the activity

```
inflater = ( LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```